# Starting docker daemon over HTTP

Tags: docker

I want to test a REST server using Postman. In Postman, I want to delete and re-create a docker instance for each test and run my test scripts.

To send delete and create Docker instance commands to the Docker daemon in Postman, I need to send commands to the daemon but the Docker daemon listens to Unix domain socket /var/run/docker.sock. So, I can't write to that socket in Postman, I need HTTP access to the Docker daemon.

How can I start the docker daemon to listen to HTTP instead of a Unix domain socket? If I can achieve this, I will be able to send commands to the Docker daemon using Postman.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can access the Docker socket, you can almost trivially root the host system.  You really don't want to make this network-accessible.  Postman is a good tool for making HTTP requests, but you'll need some other tooling to start your service.

Comment: @DavidMaze if it is possible to make the docker daemon listen an HTTP port, it may be a nice feature I think. Why should we use another tool if docker provides this?

Comment: Because it's **a major security disaster**.  You can **trivially root the entire host**.

Comment: @DavidMaze ok you're right but it may be optional. By default daemon starts via unix domain sockets, but if I want I should be able to run it over http.